# HTML frame resets or refreshes when the search button is clicked

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have 3 frames in my web page. When I click on my search button, the text in the search field goes blank and the search field itself becomes empty. Why? The frames refresh. I want to freeze them, or, I don't know, maybe add some JavaScript to stop the refresh. (Note: the query isn't in a server or a database, it's in a URL. Therefore, PHP won't work in this case.)

Comment: A code example would be useful, I can't tell what goes wrong right now.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use AJAX.. instead of having the search button submit the form, have it send request to the server, parse the results and put it in the proper frame.

You can find everything about AJAX by Googling, feel free to ask if you have any specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to direct the Search form to only reload a specific frame by using the `target` attribute on the form tag.

For instance, if you wanted your form data to only go to the "`mainFrame`" (ho ho ho) in the following scenario:

```
<html>

<frameset cols="10%,*,10%">

  <frame src="left.php" name="leftFrame" />
  <frame src="main.php" name="mainFrame" />
  <frame src="right.php" name="rightFrame" />

</frameset>

</html>
```

You would have to use the `target` attribute, like this:

```
<form action="search.php" target="mainFrame" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="search" />
  <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

As long as your search form is located in one of the other (non `mainFrame`) frames, this should leave whatever you typed in the search box.